# Cocoa: NSViewController.viewWillAppear() and viewDidAppear() not called when window was minimized to dock

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, appkit, nsviewcontroller

This question is about a macOS app, not iOS.

I have a basic Cocoa app that supports multiple windows. I noticed that `NSViewController.viewWillAppear()` and `viewDidAppear()` are not called when the app launches and the window was minimized to the dock previously.

To reproduce:

- Launch the app and open a new window
- Minimize the window to the dock (Window → Minimize)
- Quit and relaunch the app

→ The window should still be minimized in the dock

- Click on the window in the dock to bring it back on screen

Expected:

- `NSViewController.viewWillAppear()` and `viewDidAppear()` should be called

Actual:

- they are not called

This is a problem, because I need a reference to the `NSWindow` in my view controller to finish some setup so I can't simply hook into `viewDidLoad()`.

## Minimal, reproducible example

1. System Preferences → General → Uncheck "Close windows when quitting an app"
2. Xcode → New Project → macOS App:

   - User Interface: Storyboard
   - ☑︎ Create Document-Based Application
3. Open `ViewController.swift` and add:

.

```
  override func viewWillAppear() {
      super.viewWillAppear()  [PUT BREAKPOINT HERE]
  }
```

4. Open `Document.swift` and:

   1. Have `func data(ofType typeName: String)` simply return `Data()`
   2. Have `func read(from data: Data, ofType typeName: String)` do nothing (remove the exception)
5. Build & run
6. Cmd-S to save the document that opened by default
7. Window → Minimize

   - Document window now minimized in the dock
8. Cmd-Q to quit the app
9. Relaunch the app

   - Document window still sits minimized in the dock
10. Click on the document window icon in the dock to bring it back

`viewWillAppear()` and `viewDidAppear()` will not be called as the window is unminimized.

Comment: Please post a [mre]

Comment: @willeke Ok, I added a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: It looks like a bug to me. Workaround: call a setup function from `windowDidLoad` or `makeWindowControllers`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using NSWindowDidDeminiaturizeNotification on the window controller and, in that notification method, send a message to the view(s) needing this kind of update ? You could have a flag on the window controller to differentiate your case from a standard case and only send that message in the first context. Something like this :

```
 -(void) NSWindowDidDeminiaturize:(NSNotification *)notification {
     if (_justLaunched) [_myView windowDidDeminatiurizeAtLaunchTime];
     _justLaunched = NO;
}
```

Comment: That could be a workaround, but I still don't understand why viewWillAppear is not called. Clearly the view does appear at some point in time in the window's life cycle...